# How to convert a tab delimited text file to a csv file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have the following problem:

I want to convert a tab delimited text file to a csv file. The text file is the SentiWS dictionary which I want to use for a sentiment analysis ( https://github.com/MechLabEngineering/Tatort-Analyzer-ME/tree/master/SentiWS_v1.8c ).

The code I used to do this is the following:

```
txt_file = r"SentiWS_v1.8c_Positive.txt"
csv_file = r"NewProcessedDoc.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w'))

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

This code writes everything in one row but I need the data to be in three rows as normally intended from the file itself. There is also a blank line under each data and I don´t know why.

I want the data to be in this form:

**Row1**   **Row2**   **Row3**

Word       Data       Words

Word       Data       Words

instead of

**Row1**

Word,Data,Words

Word,Data,Words

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is the problem? your script seems to work fine for me. can you include a few lines of the **actual** output of your script (not just "row1 row2 row3") and then the same few lines in your desired format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

txt_file = r"SentiWS_v1.8c_Positive.txt"
csv_file = r"NewProcessedDoc.csv"

with open(txt_file, "r") as in_text:
    in_reader = csv.reader(in_text, delimiter = '\t')
    with open(csv_file, "w") as out_csv:
        out_writer = csv.writer(out_csv, newline='')
        for row in in_reader:
            out_writer.writerow(row)
```

**There is also a blank line under each data and I don´t know why.**

You're probably using a file created or edited in a Windows-based text editor. According to [the Python 3 `csv` module docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#id3):

> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the csv module does its own ([universal](https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)) newline handling.

Comment: You're welcome, @gHOsTaManTe - please upvote and mark as the accepted answer if this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 9):

```
import pandas
```

It will convert tab delimiter text file into dataframe

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("SentiWS_v1.8c_Positive.txt",delimiter="\t")
```

Write dataframe into CSV

```
dataframe.to_csv("NewProcessedDoc.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```